# access by term not working

Tags: 7, users, taxonomy-terms

I installed drupal 7, and ABT module.

Created taxonomy vocabulary 'Proj' with terms 'proj1' 'proj2'
added term ref 'Proj' field under Article cck
added term ref 'Proj' field under Users (Account settings->manage fields)

Enabled abt's Control "view" access with this field. => Yes, but allow...  on both the term ref fields (Account, article)

Created User1 (proj1 term ref)
Created User2 (proj2 term ref)

Created article PROJ1 article (proj1 term ref)
Created article PROJ1 article (proj2 term ref)

I can see both the articles as admin, but have no access to any of the articles when logged in as User1 or User2

Am I missing any step? please help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/node/1967042

Create term ref field in User account
And under article cck, add term ref under "add existing field", only then this works!!

Documentation for this module has to be updated, wasted so much of time without proper documentation. Otherwise, great module.